# Calculate density of Z = X - Y when X, Y are i.i.d with $N(2, 3^2)$

Tags: probability

Joint density of them seems to be: 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi 3^2}e^{-\frac{(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2}{2 \cdot 3^2}}
$$

Should I calculate
$$
F_Z(t) = P(X \leq Y + t)
$$
and then just $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ to obtain the density? I did similar thing with exponential distribution but here it seems way harder at glance:

$$
F_Z(t) = P(X \leq Y + t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{y+t}^{\infty} f(x,y) dy
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut is to realise that Z is also Normal, and $$E(Z)=E(X)-E(Y) = 2 - 2 = 0$$ $$Var(Z) = Var(X) + Var(Y) = 9 + 9 = 18$$

So pdf of Z is the pdf of $N(0,18)$ ie $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12.\frac{z^2}{18}} $$